Prove that these two series converge or diverge together
I would like some help to solve this problem, I have been thinking this for some time but I dont know what to do.
Let $f : (0,\infty) \to (0,\infty) $ two times differentiable with $f’$ decreases to 0
Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{f’(n)}{f(n)}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f’(n)$ both converge or diverge at the same time
I know the fact that the integral of $\frac{f’}{f}$ is $\log(f(x))$, but I dont know what to do with that.
